# Hyperlink to new page "and" scroll

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, scroll

Let's say I have two pages. When I click on the button at Page1, I want the visitor to go to Page2 **and** scroll to the #example section. These are static pages and I don't have enough knowledge to use ajax btw. Are there any jQuery plugins or anything to do something like that?

Comment: BTW have you tried something?

Comment: Animated scroll or jump?

Comment: @Jai, I have literally no idea actually. I've looked up here and googled something but found nothing.

Comment: @putvande, animated would be great but its ok to jump too

Comment: I think you dont really need any plugin to do that. Just use jQuery's own scrollTop() method and little piece of code will do it for you. Or, use the jQuery.ScrollTo  plugin.
Hope it helps.

Comment: no I know how to use scrollTop, I want the scroll to be on the second page that opens when I click. I can't target the new page with "onclick" function either.

Comment: 1.html:
    onClick="window.location.href="2.html?go=text"


2.html:
    $.urlParam = function(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
      {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
        return sParameterName[1];
        }
      }
    }

    var urlstr = $.urlParam('go');  
    var scrolpos = jQuery("a[name="+urlstr+"]").position().top;
    jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop: scrolpos}, 800);

Comment: I find it difficult to format the code in the above comment :(

But the above code should work as per your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

PAGE 1

```
<a href="PageTwoAddress\#pagetwoScrollLocation">Something in page 2</a>
```

PAGE 2

```
<a id="pagetwoScrollLocation">Something</a>
```

Link in page one will open page two and scroll to page 2

Comment: PageTwo.html\#pagetwoScrollLocation lead to PageTwo.html\#pagetwoScrollLocation (which gave me error) but href="PageTwo.html#section" worked fine for jump. Thanks, shame on me for not thinking it would be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have everything setup in your static pages which seems to be in your post:

```
$(function(){
    var toScroll = window.location.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},100, function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(toScroll).scrollTop()}, 700);
    });
});
```